# Build multiple images with Docker Compose?

Tags: docker-compose

I have a [repository](https://github.com/rfkrocktk/powerpy) which builds three different images:

1. `powerpy-base`
2. `powerpy-web`
3. `powerpy-worker`

Both `powerpy-web` and `powerpy-worker` inherit from `powerpy-base` using the `FROM` keyword in their `Dockerfile`.

I'm using Docker Compose in the project to run a Redis and RabbitMQ container. Is there a way for me to tell Docker Compose that I'd like to build the base image first and then the web and worker images?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `depends_on` to enforce an order, however that order will also be applied during "runtime" (`docker-compose up`), which may not be correct.

If you're only using compose to build images it should be fine.

You could also split it into two compose files. a `docker-compose.build.yml` which has `depends_on` for build, and a separate one for running the images as services.

These is a related issue: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/295

Answer (score 1):

About run containers:

It was bug before, but they fixed it since docker-compose v1.10.
https://blog.docker.com/2016/02/docker-1-10/

> **Start linked containers in correct order when restarting daemon:** This is a little thing, but if you’ve run into it you’ll know what a headache it is. If you restarted a daemon with linked containers, they sometimes failed to start up if the linked containers weren’t running yet. Engine will now attempt to start up containers in the correct order.

About build:
You need to build base image first.